# Why is the resistance in a double-cone conductor higher at the positive terminal?

Tags: current, resistance, simulation

I am trying to understand the current flow in a simple constricted conductor that looks like this:

[image]

And I have built a simple model that is based on charge conservation. When I simulate this in steady state, I get a voltage profile that looks like this in a 2D section:

[image]

Which makes sense. The voltage is higher at the end where I applied the current I = 1A and the voltage is zero where grounded. But now the question is... if I write the resistance as V/I, I get a resistance profile that looks like this:

[image]

Obviously, this makes sense, because V is higher on the terminal and I is constant, but it doesn't make sense from an intuition point of view. One would expect to see the highest resistance at the lowest section point, in between the cones, as in this classical picture:

[image]

I'm guessing that I would have to plot it in terms of energy density to get it to be visible there, but what do I get... the norm of the current density vector? Ix, Iy, Iz? But this is just a guess and I don't want to guess it. Can anyone please help me understand if the highest resistance would be indeed at the current terminal and not in the middle or what kind of calculations to make to get a more realistic interpretation? Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't you need to plot something like dv/di for thin slices through the cross section, or something like that? Taking total voltage divided by current is going to give the wrong result as voltage goes to zero toward the ground end.

Comment: Physther - Hi, To comply with the [site rule](/help/referencing) for content copied into a post from elsewhere, can you please add a link back to the original source webpage for any of those images which you copied or adapted from elsewhere and did not completely create yourself? Thanks.

Comment: Physther, Isn't your intuition telling you that your question is simply answered by plotting the resistivity divided by the area of the slice? If the resistivity of the material (using your approach which I won't dispute for now) is a constant, then this will rise in obvious ways as the narrower neck is approached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

This picture is showing the resistance with respect to ground seen looking in at a certain point. On the left side you have the largest resistance because it is physically far from ground, and on the right side you have a small resistance because it is physically close to ground.

I think you want to see change in resistance, which can be seen in your above plot (but isn't immediately obvious). The color gradient is "sharpest" around the chokepoint, so there is a comparatively higher change in resistance.

This can be seen in my rough graph below. Not precise, but shows the general idea, the incremental resistance is higher near the chokepoint (The same change in distance results in a larger change in resistance seen looking in).

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. But if one would want to measure the resistance of this conductor, it would still be the one that I can see on the left, if I would connect the multimeter between left and right, right?

Comment: @Physther if by "the one of the left", you mean the resistance of ~.45mΩ, then yes, the total resistance of this conductor from -2 to 0m would be ~.45mΩ.

Comment: Thank you, Michael! One more question though. If you would look at the temperature, where would the highest temperature be read? In the middle or on the left-hand side (by the current source)?

Comment: or at the Ground, considering that that's the part where it sinks?

Comment: @Physther Temperature is a function of power dissipated, so P=IV and/or V=IR you can calculate for which area dissipates the most power, which would be the hottest (ignoring factors like airflow and temperature spreading).

Answer (score 4):

Tip: use ***U*** for voltage and ***I*** for current to avoid confusion with **V** for volt and **A** for ampere.

Regarding your question we can say that the voltage drop across any slice of the cone of thickness ***dx*** will increase with the thickness but decrease with the **cross-sectional area**.